# G Suite Gmail: Default Routing vs Routing

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

In G Suite's Gmail advanced settings, there is a place for Routing and a separate tab for Default Routing. The settings are not in sync. What is the difference between them?

I am trying to setup special routings like catch-all and the some guides told me to do it in Routing while some showed me how to do it in Default Routing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've contacted the GSuite support (mail and phone) because I had the exact same question. This is the answer I received from them (translated from german):

> Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen Standard-Routing und Routing. Beim
>   Standard-Routing erstellen Sie das gesamte Routing für die Domäne. Im
>   Standard-Routing haben Sie die Möglichkeit, den verschiedenen Regeln
>   Priorität zuzuweisen, was beim Routing nicht möglich ist.
>   https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368153?hl=de#ordering

There is a difference between "Default-Routing" and "Routing". With "Default-Routing" you can create routes for the whole domain. With "Default-Routing" you can add priorities for the ruleset, which is not possible with "Routing".

> Vor einem Jahr gab es etwas namens User Level Routing. Es war auf
>   Benutzerebene verfügbar und wurde über die Admin-Konsole> Benutzer
>   erstellt. Diese Option wurde veraltet und der Abschnitt Routing wurde
>   erstellt, wenn alle zuvor erstellten Benutzer Routings sichtbar waren.
>   https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650?hl=de

Until last year (2017) there was also "User-Level-Routing". It has been available on user-level and could be created under "Admin > Users". (and now comes the weird sentence) This option has been deprecated and the section "Routing" has been created, if (when?) all formerly created User-Routings were visible.

> Mit Routing können Sie keine Priorität festlegen, und Sie können es
>   nicht zum Erstellen bestimmter Routing Vorgänge auf Domänenebene
>   verwenden.

With "Routing" you cannot add priorities and you cannot use it for creating certain routing-procedures on domain-level.

@williamli: were you able to get further insights?

Best, Chris

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 15):

There is now another routing option called "Recipient Address Maps". Google's docs still appear to be silent on when to use which type. Please see below for a discussion of what each seems to be good for. To answer your specific question, I think you can achieve the exact same result with Routing Rules and Default Routing Rules, assuming you do not need the extra power provided by Routing Rules (see below).

**Routing Rules** are the most powerful of the three types. They are not particularly well suited for forwarding many addresses as the UI is not setup to scale to have lots of rules. They CAN be used to implement “catchall” rules to route all otherwise unrecognized addresses. They can be specified per-OU. They can apply to inbound as well as outbound messages. Unlike the other rules, they can match against the sender. You can specify lists of addresses for them to apply to. They can distinguish between messages originating from internal vs. external senders.

**Default Routing Rules** sit between the other two in terms of power. They are appropriate for handling forwarding of large number of specific addresses. 1000 Default Routing rules may be specified and the admin UI is well suited for large numbers of rules. They can be used to implement “catchall” rules to route all otherwise unrecognized addresses. They are global (not specifiable per-OU). They apply only to inbound messages. They cannot distinguish between internally vs externally originating messages. They support explicit prioritization between different Default Routing Rules.

**Recipient Address Maps** are the most limited of the three (really just mapping from address A to address B) but seem to be the most appropriate for handling forwarding of large number of specific addresses. They support mapping up to 5000 addresses and the admin UI is well suited for large numbers of rules. I do NOT believe that they support a “catchall” to route all otherwise unrecognized addresses. They appear to be global (not specificable per-OU). They can apply to all incoming messages or only externally-originating messages.

Comment: One more important thing to note is the following: "Routing settings apply to active users with Gmail turned on. Routing rules don’t apply to suspended users or users who have Gmail turned off. To set up email delivery for these users, visit Set up default routing or Forward Gmail emails to another user.". (source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbefore-you-set-up-routing).

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650?hl=en we should use Default routing for most.

> Google Workspace gives admins 2 main routing settings for managing email delivery: Default routing and Routing. Use Default routing to set up the default mail delivery for your organization. For example, if you want to send all or most of your organization's email to multiple inboxes, use Default routing and set up dual delivery. Then, use the Routing setting to create more specialized email delivery rules, or to override the Default routing behavior.